# Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'string[]'

Tags: typescript

I am trying to replace spaces with underscores on strings, since there are some discrepancies with the data I am getting from an API and the thing I am comparing with.

I am adding a property as I map an array, and I am using `replace` to convert the role string on both the `data` array and the `roleIndex` array

```
const sortedArray = data
  .map(employee => ({
    ...employee,
    rank: roleIndex.findIndex(role => role.replace(/\s+/g, '_').includes(employee.role.replace(/\s+/g, '_'))) +1 || 100
  }))
```

But TypeScript complains with:

```
`Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'string[]'.(2339)`
```

Here is the whole code to replicate the problem:
https://tsplay.dev/zwODlN

---- Update

Thanks to @Viet and @Andreas for pointing out that the `roleIndex` are  arrays and not strings, so I added another `map` method

```
const sortedArray = data
  .map(employee => ({
    ...employee,
    rank: roleIndex.findIndex(role => role
           .map((v) => v.replace(/\s+/g, '_'))
           .includes(employee.role.replace(/\s+/g, '_'))) +1 || 100
  }))
```

Comment: Either `role` or `employee.role` is an array of strings and therefor has no `.replace()` method -> [mcve]

Comment: And why all those tags? Why `reactjs`? Why the `ecmascript-X` tags?

Comment: Well I am running this on react, but it could be just TypeScript, as the example proves it happens on TypeScript playground too, I am removing the tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, because each item in roleIndex is an array, not a string:

```
const roleIndex = [
  ['Managing Director'],
  ['Operations Director', 'Head of Client Services'],
  ['Head of Sales and Marketing', 'Director of Performance and Innovation'],
  ['Head of Digital', 'PR and Promotion']
]
```

So you have to access first element like this:

```
    rank: roleIndex.findIndex(role => role[0].replace(/\s+/g, '_').includes(employee.role.replace(/\s+/g, '_'))) +1 || 100
```

Comment: Ok, got it just added a map on each, thanks